# Recursive query to retrieve all child from given id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am migrating from oracle to postgres and I don't know how to make a recursive query

Here is an example data set:

| id | id_parent | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | aa |
| 2 | 0 | aa |
| 3 | 1 | aa |
| 4 | 3 | aa |
| 5 | 3 | aa |
| 6 | 2 | aa |
| 7 | 6 | aa |

For id = 3, I want to get

| id |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

for id =1

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

with this I have all but I don't know how to filter by id:

```
SELECT id FROM (  
        with recursive cat as ( 
            select * from table
             union all 
            select  table.* 
            from table  
            join cat on cat.id_parent = table.id
        ) 
        select  * from cat order by id 
    )
    as listado where id != '0'  group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of using sub-query. You just need to fix your recursive query only as -

```
WITH RECURSIVE cat (id, id_parent) as 
    ( 
     SELECT id, id_parent
       FROM table
      WHERE id = 1
      UNION ALL
     SELECT d.id, d.id_parent
       FROM table d
       JOIN cat ON cat.id = d.id_parent
    ) 
SELECT id 
  FROM cat 
 ORDER BY id;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=99173ee1a6e3d943e18f88925043657a)